# PyTorch Lightening: load model from pre-trained; values of weights remains same

Tags: nlp, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-geometric

I have a pre-trained model, by changing final fc layers I have created model for downstream task. Now, I want to load weights from pertained weights. I tried `self.model.load_from_checkpoint (self.pretrained_model_path)`. But, when I print weight values from model layers, they are exactly same which indicates weights were not loaded/updated. Note that is not giving me any warning/error.

Edit:

```
self.model.backbone = self.model.load_from_checkpoint (self.pretrained_model_path).backbone
```

updates the parameters with pre_trained weights. There might be optimal way but I found this fix.

Comment: Can you share some more code snippet? Also, did you try printing the weights that you are trying to load?

Comment: `print ( list(self.model.backbone.conv[0].parameters()))`

`self.model = self.model.load_from_checkpoint (self.pretrained_model_path)` 
 `print ( list(self.model.backbone.conv[0].parameters()))`

Comment: By printing the weights, I am verifying if I got new weights or not